# Is it normal multiconfig is very slow to parse?

Tags: yocto

I have tried using the [multiconfig setup](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#platdev-building-targets-with-multiple-configurations) for 6 machines but it is extremely slow, around 7 times slower.

I tested by just parsing (`-p`) one image for one machine on both setup.

Is it possible some optimizations were not done and the feature is not completely ready?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

multiconfig allows the setups to run in parallel and the seventh setup is likely the "no multiconfig" setup which many people overlook when counting them.

multiconfig is not expected to generate parsing speed improvements, its designed to let you run multiple builds with parallelisation and a simple command. This is therefore not something which has been optimized or is planned to be optimized either, at least as things stand as that isn't an area where we can see optimizations we can make.

Comment: This answers the question. Nevertheless, I noticed one thing that can be improved and actually generating errors. If I try to compile 2 packages of the same architecture in parallel, e.g raspberrypi3:gcc and raspberrypi-cm3:gcc, it will attempt sometimes to execute same task twice in parallel leading to `FileExists` or compilation errors

Comment: I'd suggest filing a bug in https://bugzilla.yoctoproject.org/ with details about the setup you tried, the error you saw and what you think should have happened. Unfortunately the detection of misconfiguration or layer/machine incompatibilities is limited right now.

Comment: I also thought so. Thanks